# Moving Windows 10 to SSD from HDD - SSD is not visible in BIOS boot options

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, windows-10, format

I have a fairly new Acer desktop that I just upgraded to 10. I bought a Samsung SSD that I'd like to move my Windows installation and programs over to. It's more than big enough to fit all of the data from the existing partition(it's not much beyond a vanilla Windows), so that shouldn't be an issue.

I formatted the SSD as a simple GPT partition using Disk Management. Then I used "EaseUS Todo Backup"(per a LifeHacker guide) to clone my C: partition to the SSD. As far as I can tell, that worked. Windows sees the drive just fine, and all of the data appears to be there. It's identical to C: as far as I can see.

Here's the problem: the BIOS does not see the drive as an option to boot from in the boot order menu. All I see is "Windows Boot Manager" as the only option. I haven't done anything like this in years so I'm unfamiliar with that and I'm not sure what to look for. I tried going through Settings to reboot the computer in what I think is "Windows Boot Manager" and I didn't see anything relevant to my issue.

It's visible elsewhere in the BIOS(and by Windows) so it's obviously not a connection issue. I tried unplugging the existing HDD, that didn't change anything(and obviously it didn't boot).

Any ideas to debug this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Windows 10 from new onto my laptops old harddrive, and used the EaseUS todo backup to clone it.

It worked fine - a few notes

1. I did a sector by sector copy. That probably is overkill, so try item 2 first before you do this again assuming you still have the SSD with the image.
2. Force AHCI mode in your BIOS. My Samsung Chronos was set to automatic, and that did NOT work.  Forcing it (manual - enabled) did the job
3. Just in case, I also did the same for my wife's Sony laptop, but it didn't have the option to change AHCI mode, however a BIOS upgrade fixed the problem and the Windows 10 upgrade then went ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess people think they will save time not having to reinstall all their applications and stuff by migrating their HDD install to SSD.

The truth of it is, by the time you've created the backup, migrated it to your SSD, messed about with the settings to get it to boot and spent time troubleshooting the issues that arise post-migration, you will have spent a lot longer doing that than if you'd just done a clean install on to your new SSD and reinstalled everything.

Following a clean reinstall, your system will run smoother, you'll have less clutter since you will only re-install the apps and games you actually want, and you don't have to worry about partition sizes, enabling TRIM, disabling auto-defragment, prefetch, recovery partitions and all that stuff since the Windows installer will handle all of that when it detects that it's being installed on SSD.

It might seem like it's going to take forever to reinstall and download all your stuff again, but it really doesn't. Windows 10 is really rapid at installing these days.